# How to display grouped by barchart and raw data line with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've aggregated values by month to display as a bar chart using Pandas TimeGrouper:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx',index_col='Date')
g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M"))
g[['Money Out','Money in']].sum().plot(kind='bar',ax=ax)
```

Which gives me this output:

[image: bar chart]

But I also want to display the raw data on this same chart as a line series, for example:

```
df['Balance'].plot(ax=ax)
```

To give this:

[image: series]

However, when I plot both together, only the bar chart shows, even though the x axis appears to me to be dates that should be compatible.

**EDIT**
Here is an example of the data when printed.
[image]

Comment: Can you add an example? For instance `print(df.head(20))`.

Comment: @IanS I've added printed output now, let me know if you want anything else. Cheers

Comment: It would be much better if you copied the result as text. See [general advice here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: This is a [known issue when the x-axis is a DateTimeIndex](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10761#issuecomment-128807571). The link points you to a comment that has a workaround.

Comment: Last comment: I would recommend plotting the balance as `df.Balance.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).nth(-1)`, which is the last balance of the month.

Comment: @IanS thanks for the tips and pointing out that existing issue - I hadn't seen that yet. Cheers.